# struct in c getting problematic, at verge of improper result

Tags: c++, c, database, struct, dev-c++

I have the following struct

```
struct statistics {
    int result[100],steps[100],gamecounter;
    float time[100];
};
typedef struct statistics GAMEST;
```

In my functions I call it like this

```
GAMEST gamesStruct;
gamesStruct.result[2]=res;
gamesStruct.steps[2]=step;
gamesStruct.time[2]=tim;
```

At the moment I assign values to the struct its all good and the data are fine. But when I try to print value that I assigned previously for example gamesStruct.result[0] what I get
is a big number which looks like a memory address like if the gamesStruct.result[0] is empty.

Any ideas ?

Here is some more code

```
 int stats(int res,int gamenum,int step,float tim,int counter){
GAMEST gamesStruct;
char vic[3][7];
if(gamenum>=0){
    strcpy(vic[0],"Draw");
    strcpy(vic[1],"Victory");
    strcpy(vic[2],"Loss");
    gamesStruct.result[gamenum]=res;
    gamesStruct.steps[gamenum]=step;
    gamesStruct.time[gamenum]=tim;
}else{
    printf("Stats per game :\n\n");
    system("pause");
    for(int i=0;i<=counter;i++){
        int tmp=gamesStruct.result[0];
        printf("%d",gamesStruct.result[0]);
    system("pause");
    system("pause");
        printf("Game %d : %s in %d moves and %f seconds\n\n",i+1,vic[tmp],gamesStruct.steps[i],gamesStruct.time[i]);
    }   
    printf("out");
    system("pause");
    int ressum[3]={0,0,0};
    int stepsum=0;
    int timesum=0;
    printf("2");
    system("pause");
    for(int i=0;i<=counter;i++){
        ressum[gamesStruct.result[i]]=ressum[gamesStruct.result[i]]+gamesStruct.result[i];
        stepsum=stepsum+gamesStruct.steps[i];
        timesum=timesum+gamesStruct.time[i];
    }
    float resmid[3],stepmid,timemid;
    resmid[0]=resmid[0]/(counter+1);
    resmid[1]=resmid[1]/(counter+1);
    resmid[2]=resmid[2]/(counter+1);
    stepmid=stepmid/(counter+1);
    timemid=timemid/(counter+1);
    printf("\n\nAverage stats for %d games:\n\n",counter+1);
    printf("\nVictories :%f  Losses :%f  Draws :%f  \n",resmid[1],resmid[2],resmid[0]);
    printf("\nAverage moves :%f and Time :%f\n\n",stepmid,timemid);
}


return(0);
```

}

If gamenum is bigger or equal to 0  my function assigns values properly to the struct.
But when i try to print them my program crashes because the data is wrong

I want to point out that I HAVE assigned values before I try to access them, thats is my problem

Comment: [learn how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  [Post a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value

Comment: @vines my problem is that i assign a value in position 0 and when I assign in the next position of the array the previous is gone . My question is not about empty variables is about variables not maintaining their value

Comment: @mremremre1, compilers don't do any magic, unless you do. Try to debug, or post relevant, reproducible code.

Comment: @mremremre1 - if you want our help, you need to show us more information - like others told you - show us a Minimal, Complete and Valid example...

Comment: @NirMH I added more code

Comment: @mremremre1 which is nowhere near *minimal* still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code - assuming the function `stats` is being executed one per game iteration. the `gamesStruct` local variable is being destroyed at end of `stats` and being declared (and initialized) again and again.

this is why the previous result is cleared.

you should declare the `gamesStruct` at tge calling API and pass it by reference to the `stats` method.

```
int stats(GAMEST& gamesStruct, int res,int gamenum,int step,float tim,int counter)
{
   ...  // same as before
}
```

(pay attention to create the `gamesStruct` before calling the iteration and destroy it properly if dynamically allocated.

Comment: You mean that i should pass it as a parameter of the stats function ? The struct is being called by many other functions , should i declare it as global ?

Comment: yes, exactly - if you declared it locally to the method, its memory is being returned to the OS at end of the method

Comment: i want the struct to keep the data as long as the program is running. Should i declare it as extern or inside main ?

Comment: yes. declare it on main, and pass it by reference

Comment: in main i call stats like this ? stats(gamesStruct,0,-1,0,0,gamecounter);